# Redirect Traffic on OVS switch

Tags: networking, linux-networking, arp

I have below topology on mininet:

Host1:10.0.0.1/24 mac :aa:00:00:00:00:01
Host2:10.0.0.2/24 mac :aa:00:00:00:00:02
Host3:10.0.0.3/24 mac :aa:00:00:00:00:03

I want to redirect traffic as below:

When host1 ping host 2 the traffic should be redirected to host3.

I have implemented below rule on osv switch and ryu controller:

sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 "table=0,priority=100,ip,in_port=1,dl_src=aa:00:00:00:00:01,nw_dst=10.0.0.2,actions=mod_dl_src:aa:00:00:00:00:03,mod_nw_dst:10.0.0.3,output:3"

sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 "table=0,priority=100,ip,in_port=3,dl_src=aa:00:00:00:00:03,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,actions=mod_dl_src:aa:00:00:00:00:02,mod_nw_dst:10.0.0.2,output:1"

The host 3 is receiving ICMP request but not replying.
I believe its an ARP problem.

Can anyone help please help for this redirection?